# How to enable logging in uwsgi?

Tags: logging, ubuntu-16.04, uwsgi, supervisord

Os: ubuntu16.04

The command in supervisor config file is :

`command=uwsgi --socket 127.0.0.1:16657 --master --module web.wsgi --chdir /path/to/directory --env DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=web.settings --processes 32 --threads 100 --max-requests=5000 --listen 65535 --vacuum -b 65535`

How to enable in logging uwsgi?
or anywhere else to change the uwsgi.ini file?

i am using `--logto` `path/to/store/log`

but in log file we didn't get logs.

How to enable uwsgi logs and the logs should be in json format?

Answer (score 1):

```
daemonize= /home/ubuntu/sample/uwsgi.log
```

Please add the above to your ini file, else refer [this](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Logging.html#basic-logging)